# Showing dialog on Android disables windows focus so onKeyDown wont listen for touch events

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using the following code to listen for volume buttons on my activity, which implements View.OnTouchListener:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        triggerFinalSoundDialogue(2);
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
        triggerFinalSoundDialogue(2);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Problem is that triggerFinalSoundDialogue creates a dialog, which makes the window lose focus, so I get this:

```
 Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, scanCode=114, metaState=0, flags=0x28, repeatCount=0, eventTime=15688166, downTime=15688002, deviceId=9, source=0x101 }
```

and the activity stops listening for the volume touch. I want to listen for it while the dialog is showing so I can raise the volume on the dialog

**UPDATE:**

```
public static AlertDialog showDialog(Context context, View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setView(view);
    return alert;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

based on the answer above I did:

```
dialogVolumeAllBinding = DialogVolumeAllBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(StompaiMainActivity.this));
volumeDialog = UiUtil.showDialog(this, dialogVolumeAllBinding.getRoot());

Window window = volumeDialog.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
volumeDialog.show();
```

but the dialog still steals the volume events and I still get:

```
Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent
```

Comment: Please complete your question.

Comment: @JavadDehban it is complete

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to show the dialog?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai updated, see

Comment: Any reason you call `triggerFinalSoundDialogue` in both up and down events?

Comment: @tynn it's just a way to show the dialog calling `show` on it. The answer from BlackHatSamurai worked but I can't make it dismiss on touch outside of the dialog, do you know why?

Comment: I asked, because it could be sufficient to only call it in UP. The dialog can't be dismissed, because it does not focus and thus doesn't receive the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run you old code on my Android 10 device, but your bug does not reappear: the alert dialog does not impact the activity KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) and volume widget's touch event. This is my demo code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
            triggerFinalSoundDialogue(2);
        }
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
            triggerFinalSoundDialogue(2);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void triggerFinalSoundDialogue(int type){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(LongClickDeleteWidgetActivity.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_mode_stop);
        showDialog(LongClickDeleteWidgetActivity.this, imageView).show();
    }

    public AlertDialog showDialog(Context context, View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setView(view);
        return alert;
    }
```

ps: If you really want to control the touch event, you could be note the touch event in the Dialog window and the activity, and understanding the mechanism of touch event delivery between them.

Hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your alert, you can set a flag for the window like so:

```
public static AlertDialog showDialog(Context context, View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        Window window = alert.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        alert.setView(view);
        return alert;
    }
```

Using the `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag will allow you to send touch events to the activity behind the alert.

Per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL):

> FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
>
> public static final int FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
>
> Window flag: this window won't ever get key input focus, so the user can not send key or other button events to it. Those will instead go to whatever focusable window is behind it. This flag will also enable FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL whether or not that is explicitly set.
>
> Setting this flag also implies that the window will not need to interact with a soft input method, so it will be Z-ordered and positioned independently of any active input method (typically this means it gets Z-ordered on top of the input method, so it can use the full screen for its content and cover the input method if needed. You can use FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM to modify this behavior. * @apiSince 1

Comment: it didn't work. Can you take a look at my update to see if I'm doing correctly?

Comment: You didn't do it the way I showed, you set the flag on the view, not the dialog object. See update.

Comment: It worked, but now I can't dimiss the dialog by clicking outside it. It has no focus so what should I do?

Comment: I'm confused now. You want to be able to click outside the alert to turn up and down the volume; but you also want the click to close the alert? I'm confused. I would say you should post a new question for the new problem and have this one accepted.

Comment: @Paprika You can always set an `onClickListener` to the activity behind the dialog to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why posted this answer

- Surely BlackHatSamurai has solved the problem needed for the question, however, there was an additional query which is not answered and since Comments section has a restricted space I posted this answer.
- Note the additional query is about closing the dialog in a similar way like onTouchOutside would do while at the same time maintaining the FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE behavior.

#### Solution discussion then after that the code

- We will use onTouchEvent in the activity that launches the dialog and there we will check if we need to dismiss the dialog.
- Also I added dismissing dialog in case of on back pressed while is shown, I figured you might need that as well as you needed on touch outside.
- I added comments in the code to make everything as clear as possible.

#### Code

**Activity.java**

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.maproductions.mohamedalaa.stackoverflow_solutions.R;

import mohamedalaa.mautils.core_android.extensions.ContextUtils;

public class VolumeKeysControlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlertDialog dialog;

    private GestureDetector detector;

    private GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_volume_keys_control);

        detector = new GestureDetector(this, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            if (dialog == null) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_volume_keys_control, null, false);
                dialog = showAlertDialog(this, view);
            }else if (! dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.show();
            }

            // Showing toast to make sure even when dialog is shown, pressing volume keys still
            // invokes this part of the code and not consumed by dialog window.
            String upOrDown = keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ? "Down" : "Up";
            // Just a utility method for Toast.makeText(params).show();
            ContextUtils.toast(this, "Clicked volume " + upOrDown);

            return true;
        }else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            // Since you want canceled on touch outside, I figured you would want as well on back
            // press to dismiss dialog if shown instead for ex. navigating back to previous activity.
            dialog.dismiss();

            return true;
        }

        // Just FYI, I think it's better to return true only if you consumed the action so inside
        // if statements and here instead use -> super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); UNLESS you are
        // aware of that and actually wanna consume all actions.
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            // GestureDetector is used so that on click outside dismisses the dialog instead of
            // calling directly dismiss dialog here, since here any touch will invoke this part
            // of the code, while detector takes care of just checking for onSingleTapConfirmed
            // as what the listener has specified.
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private AlertDialog showAlertDialog(Context context, View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            // Add flags is same as setFlags(flag, flag)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        }

        dialog.setView(view);

        // Showing dialog since the method names says showing dialog not just creating it.
        dialog.show();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

#### Additional Notes

- Even if the dialog is so simple DialogFragment is highly recommended by Google over Dialog, you can search in google for advantages of DialogFragment over Dialog.